# React-Native: Is it possible to get the layout positions of the FlatList

Tags: react-native, viewport, react-native-flatlist

[image]

As I indicated in the Picture with arrow mark, I would like to get the top positions of `FlatList`. I tried `onLayout` props, But it return only null values.

Is there anyway to get the top positions of `FlatList`?

Comment: Could you share your try or try wrapping your ```FlatList``` inside a ```<View onLayout={ }>```

Answer (score -1):

Check below sample

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  findDimesions = layout => {
    const {x, y, width, height} = layout;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onLayout={event => this.findDimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout)}
        style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Change this according to your requirements.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: It gives the layout position when rendered for the first time. But, Can I get X and Y positions as i am scrolling through Items?

Comment: @Kishore if you want to get the position of individual values, place ```onLayout``` inside your ```renderItem```.

Comment: I did so, Each item is returning the position from it's predecessor. But i would like to get the position from top of the screen. What can i do for that?

Comment: @Mighty top position is returning from the above code.

Comment: I want the position of individual item from top. But your code gives the position of the `FlatList` which is always zero

Answer (score -1):

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.top} />
        <FlatList
          ...
        />
    </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    top: { flex: 0 },
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can add some explanation.